# How can I add "\t" at visual studio 2013 replace with regular expression

Tags: visual-studio-2013, replace

How can I replace text from ***stm << "filename"***  to  ***stm << "\tfilename"*** in visual studio 2013 find&replace with regular expression.

I try to find ***stm << ("filename")*** and replace to ***stm << "\t" << $1***.

but it was changed to ***stm << "  " << "filename"***.

and I try to replace ***stm << "\\t" << $1***.

it was change to ***stm << "\\t" << "filename"***.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013, press Ctrl+F to open search box. Below search box there are 3 symbols, as known as 3 types of searching:

- Match case ( Alt + C)
- Match whole word ( Alt + W)
- Use Regular Expressions ( Alt + E)

Use Regular Expressions to search what you want

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i know it. if you try this, you know what i mean. I think this is visual studio bug. I can't replace text to "\t". not real tab. "\t"

Comment: Oh. i'm sorry for my mistake. i fixed last line of my question.